# Checkmarx: Missing HSTS Header in React Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, security, hsts

I have performed Checkmarx scan on React application. It is showing following scan result:

**Missing HSTS Header :**
The web-application does not define an HSTS header, leaving it vulnerable to attack.

Error is showing for following highlighted code:

```
const client = async (endpoint, customConfig, isStaticContent) => {
     return fetch(fullUrl, config).then((response) => {
          if (typeof response?.setHeader === 'function') {
            response?.setHeader(
                'Strict-Transport-Security',
                'max-age=63072000', //error showing for this line
                'includeSubDomains'
            )
          }
     })
}
```

I have checked in response header on chrome dev tools.
Application has following header:

*strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains*

How to resolve this checkmarx issue ?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72088572/297076), all of your HSTS values must be on the same line for Checkmarx to pass. For example:

```js
response?.setHeader(
                'Strict-Transport-Security',
                'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains'
)
```